# Multiply by two then every three years by three

Tags: java

I am working on an assignment that asks:

**Magic Plant**

We have a magic plant that once it is planted, it germinates and grows two leaves in the first
year. It doubles its leaves every year except that every three years it triples its leaves.

Something like:

```
Year:   1 | 2 | 3 |  4|  5| 6 |  7 …  
Leaves: 2 | 4 | 12| 24| 48|144|288 …
```

What I have completed so far:

```
int n = 0;
int l = 6;

for(int i = 2; i>-1; i++) {
    if(i == l) {
        break;
    }
    if(i != l) {
        n = 2 * i;
    }
    if(i == l) {
        break;
    }
    if(i != l) {
        n = 3 * i;
    }
    System.out.println(n);
}
```

My thought process behind that was to check if it passed the year 6 before it multiplied it by two and then by three on the third year, then repeat.

This does not work the output is:

3
6
9
15

I need to be able to input a year and find a number of leaves,
as well as take the number of leaves and find out how old the plant is.

Comment: Please read [mcve] and then edit your question to make it clear what you are exactly asking. We can't read your mind.

Comment: `java !== javascript`

Comment: 1) A variable named `l` is high discouraged, because it can be confused with the number `1`, depending on font. --- 2) For you logic, don't try to calculate `n` as a function of `i`. The rule is that the value of `n` doubles/triples every iteration, so calculate `n` as a function of `n`, i.e. `n *= 2` or `n *= 3`. --- 3) Don't use `break` to exit the loop. Just use a normal `for` loop, i.e. `for (int year = 1; year <= 6; year++)`. --- 4) Then use the modulo operator to check if it is every third year, i.e. `if (year % 3 == 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

```
int years = 30; //number of years
long leaves = 0; //long is better because int will overflow faster

for(int i = 0 ; i < years ; ++i){
    if(i == 0)//first year
        leaves += 2;//adds 2 leaves
    else if(i % 3 == 0) //Every third year
        leaves *= 3; //triple leaves
    else//every other year
        leaves *= 2; //doubles leaves
    System.out.println(leaves);
}
```

will print:

```
2
4
8
24
48
96
288
576
...
```

Test the code [here](https://repl.it/N5q1/1)

You could use the [mod or remainder operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html) (%), it's pretty handy for this kind of tasks.

I recommend using better names for your variables since it can be detrimental in the long run; use self explanatory names like `numberOfLeaves` instead of `n` and `sixthYear` instead of `l`.

Using this knowledge you could get the number of years of the tree, since it's an assignment (for collegue I guess...) I'll not put the code for that but I will give you a hint of a way to do it: substract inside a loop until you have zero leaves.

Answer (score 0):

```
   public static void main(String [] args)
    {
     String years = "";
     String leave = "";
        int num_years = 10;
        int leave_count = 1;
        for(int i=1;i<= num_years;i++) {
            leave_count = (i%3 == 0)? leave_count * 3:leave_count*2; 
            years = years + i +"|";
            leave = leave + leave_count + "|";
        }
    System.out.println(years+"\n"+leave);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive way to do it.

```
private static int[] numberOfLeaves(int year) {
    if (year > 1) {
        if (year % 3 != 0) {
            int[] ret1 = new int[2];
            ret1[0] = ++numberOfLeaves(year - 1)[0];
            ret1[1] = numberOfLeaves(year - 1)[1] * 2;
            return ret1;
        } else {
            int[] ret2 = new int[2];
            ret2[0] = ++numberOfLeaves(year - 1)[0];
            ret2[1] = numberOfLeaves(year - 1)[1] * 3;
            return ret2;
        }
    }
    int[] ret = new int[2];
    ret[0] = year;
    ret[1] = year * 2;
    return ret;
}
```

It is tested. When you print out the data, you should access it by index (ret[0] for number of years and ret[1] for number of leaves.).